# Android Studio 2.3.3: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0 even with Maven

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio

I'm working on one of my first apps on Android Studio and want to add advertisements to it using Admob. In my gradle: project I have Maven:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()

    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my app-level build.gradle dependencies as well

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Even though I have Maven in repositories I still get the error message: 
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0

Shouldn't maven {url "https://maven.google.com"} be enough to import the Mobile Ads sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go

> Tools>Android>SDK MANAGER>SDK TOOLS

and check for latest version(11.8.0) of Google Play services and Ok.
Finally , in build.gradle see that they have the same version.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxSpw.png)